# "Enable Field Service Lightning" missing in some dev orgs

Tags: winter17, field-service-lightning

I have a few dev orgs created before Winter '17, as well as a preview org I created last week. All of them are on Winter '17 now but only the preview org shows "Enable Field Service Lightning" under Setup > Build > Customize > Field Service > Field Service Settings. The rest of the dev orgs just have "Enable Work Orders". Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: There seems to be a lack of documentation here. The Help docs explain where to find Enable Field Service Lightning but they do not explain why orgs don't have that option.